# Calculate the average Pointwise Information of a query that has more than two strings?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, full-text-search, nlp, information-retrieval

Lets say we have a query that constitutes the following 4 strings  w1,w2,w3 and w4

The pointwise mutual information(PMI) between two string is denoted as: p(w_i,w_j) = log(p(w_i,w_j)/(p(w_i)*p(w_j)))

To find the average PMI, one would naturally calculate the PMI for all the pairs and average it. But what do we do in cases where for the pairs in consideration, there are no common documents?

Ex: Lets say w1 and w2 have no common documents, which in turn means that p(w1,w2) = 0 and a PMI of Infinity. How do we take an average then? Do we neglect the pairs whose PMI is infinity? If we do neglect such pairs, then what should we do in cases where none of the strings in the query would have any common documents?

Answer (score 1):

Standard answer: when estimating probabilities, smooth.

Thus assuming p(w_1) is the probability that a document contains w_1, if the query w_1 returns n_1 documents from N total, you switch your estimate for p(w_1) from:

n_1 / N (unsmoothed estimate, otherwise known as Maximum Likelihood)

to:

(n_1 + 1) / (n_2 + 2) (actually the posterior mean of the parameter assuming uniform prior).

This means you never get zeros anywhere. Similarly for empirical estimates of joint probability p(w_1, w_2), use:

(count(w_1 and w_2) + 1) / (N + 2)

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for your comment. I agree with the smoothing idea, I guess the question would then progress to the choice of the smoothing parameter. Putting that aside for a bit, do you think it would make sense to just call the whole thing zer0 i.e., PMI =0, when we can't find intersections in the corpus? As per the logic of the formula, this would translate into two entities that are independent of each other

Comment: I think using alpha=1 for smoothing is fine. It corresponds to a uniform prior on your parameters, and is unlikely to matter that much unless you have very small data. I would not recommend just using PMI=0, because you won't be able to differentiate between pairs that were all 0 probability vs those where only one element was.